# analysis terminates while using openseesMP?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to model a soil-structure system using openseesMP. However, I get this error and the analysis terminates:

`FATAL::MeshRegion::getNodes(void) - no nodes yet set`

What does that mean?

Comment: What does this have to do with the `tcl` language? It looks like an application-specific problem.

Comment: Also, at a guess you should set some nodes before calling the analysis. No idea how.